# PHP URI Mapping With Functions

Tags: php, routes, uri

I am developing a php application that will use the same principals as an MVC system, however, I do not want to use classes.  What I am trying to accomplish is to have SEO URL's (mysite.com/product/Some-Cool-Product/123) without the need for classes.  The methods will instead use functions.  The biggest problem I am encountering is mapping the URI's to the appropriate files and functions.  For example, mysite.com/members/profile/123 would point to the file 'sources/members.php' and would then call the 'profile' function.  What causes the problem is adding the ability to use directories for my source files.  If I wanted to use a url such as 'mysite.com/forums/threads/view/12345' would point to 'sources/forums/threads.php  and would call the 'view' function with the id as an argument.

Can anybody help me out with this?  Here's what I have so far.

```
<?php 

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$uri = ltrim($uri, '/');

$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri);

$invalid = 0;

foreach($uri_segments as $key => $val){

    if(!preg_match('^[a-z0-9]^', $val)){

        $invalid = $invalid + 1;

    }

}

if($invalid > 0){

    die('Could not execute the script... the uri contains invalid characters.');

} else {

    //Load the script.

}

?>
```

Comment: Why the hell wouldn't you use classes? :) Just out of curiosity.

Comment: there's never a "need" for classes. it's whether or not you enjoy self inflicting pain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're using the LAMP stack here (Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP).

If you are using Apache as the web server, you can setup a .htaccess file in your public directory with a rewrite rule which will automatically do this for you. So that way when someones hits:

http://www.mysite.com/forums/threads/view/12345

It would automatically load **'sources/members.php'** and pass in the id from the URL as a get parameter that would show up in the $_GET array.

In the directory where your index (index.html/index.php) file resides create a file named **".htaccess"**

An example of your **.htaccess** file would be:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^forums/threads/view/([0-9]+) sources/members.php?thread_id=$1
```

If this doesn't work, it could possibly be because your Apache configuration is misconfigured or the rewrite rule is malformed. Either way, this is much faster than using PHP not only code writing wise but performance wise as well.

Here goes an external resource that might help as well:
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

Make all requests that aren't files go through index.php. Make a Router.php - require this in index.php - parse the request in Router.php and include the files you need from there.

In your Router.php, you need to at least know a pattern to look for in the uri. Try mapping this pattern in some form of XML and anything that can't be matched to your pattern should go to a 404 page.

Sorry, vague.. but this is a big question. someone could elaborate on it for a long time.